How to get user list from discord using express.js
Hello everyone i have a question. I'm trying to create a list of players in express.js who have a given role. I'm creating this using discord.js but I can't format it properly to display it correctly. here is my code.
function getUsersWithRole(guildId, roleId) {
    const { Client, GatewayIntentBits} = require("discord.js");
    const client = new Client({
        intents: [
            GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
            GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        ],
    });
    client.once("ready", async () => {
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);
        const role = guild.roles.cache.get(roleId);
        console.log(role)
    });
    client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
}

exports.all_users = (req, res) => {
    const user = req.session.user;
    const ADM = req.session.admin;
    if (!ADM) res.redirect("/initoauth");
    else {
        try {
            const usersWithRole = getUsersWithRole('1084491038212755617', '1084491038212755620');
            res.render('all_users', { serverName, users: usersWithRole });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
        }
    }
};

I tried to fix it using various methods but all failed
